# Get Only id and href

Tags: java, screen-scraping, screen, htmlunit

My output consists of multipe id and href and other data.

How to get all the id and href values using Htmlunit and Java code?

I need to get all the href values mandatory but id is not mandatory...

How can I do that and where should I write the given code.

```
<a id="Repeater1_ctl00_HyperLink2" href="/jobs/Physical-Security-Specialist-308550900.html">

<a id="Repeater1_ctl05_HyperLink1" href="/jobs/Safety-and-Occup-Hlth-Specialist-308549000.html">

<a id="Repeater1_ctl08_HyperLink2" href="/jobs/Nurse-Practitioner-Oca-Esep-Dh-308526400.html">

<a id="Repeater1_ctl09_HyperLink1" href="/jobs/Nurse-Practitioner-Oca-Esep-Dh-308526400.html">
```

etc.....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid we will not be able to help you since your question lacks detail. What did you try so far, what was the result? Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I'm not writing code for you :) But I can give you an idea of the solution.

Get the HtmlPage. Try getting all the HtmlAnchor object of the page (you can use XPath for this). Iterate over the HtmlAnchor collection and execute the method [getHrefAttribute()](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlAnchor.html#getHrefAttribute%28%29) to get the href attribute. Similary use the getId() method of the HtmlAnchor to get its id. That's it :)